# When cloning a table row, how do I only clone one value of the previous inputs instead of all of them?

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, clone

I have a table that contains inputs in the  to add data to my database. In my jquery function I have a click event that submits the data and then it creates a clone of the table row so I can add in another data input. Right now, the clone copies all of the input values from the previous row into the next row, however I only want to copy one value over to the next row.

This is the function I'm using to clone a new row. It copies over the project_id, cost, and hours value. However I only want it to copy over the project_id value.

```
$('#addRow').click(function(e) {
        const cloneRow = $('#tableData tbody tr').first();
        let data = {
         project_id: $(".project_id").last().val(),
         imp_or_ann: $(".imp_or_ann").last().val(),
         category: $(".category").last().val(),
         cost: $(".cost").last().val(),
         hours: $(".hours").last().val()
    }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/costs_hours',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data
        }).then(
            cloneRow.clone().appendTo('#tableData tbody'),
            $("#next").removeAttr('disabled')
        )

    })
```

Comment: I see two relatively straight forward ways:

First option: do not clone the element, instead create a new one with exactly the data you want.

Second option: create a clone and store it in a value, edit it and then append it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that with what you currently have would be to reset the values of the fields. It's not ideal, there are other ways to do this, like using a template (an actual `<template>` or a hidden regular-`<tr>`), or constructing the elements programmatically, but it should work.

```
var newRow=cloneRow.clone().appendTo('#tableData tbody');
newRow.find(".imp_or_ann,.category,.cost,.hours").val(null); //or whatever the default may be
```